# 'Class' has no attribute to 'rect'

Tags: class, pygame

```py
skier.move(hastighet)

self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx + speed[0]
```

I was not able to post my entire code here cause this website thought it wasn't properly formatted.

I get the error message

> ```py
> 'ClassSkier' has no attribute 'rect'
> ```

I literally copied this code from a book so I have no idea why it's not working. The faulty lines are the ones i copied in above.

Comment: Read the error message! It means that the class 'ClassSkier' has not attribute `.rect`. In other words `self.rect` does not exist. Probably you have to set `self.rect` in the constructor of the class `ClassSkier`. Possibly `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`?

Comment: Python is trying to tell you that `skier` doesn't have an attribute `rect`. This probably means it hasn't been initialized. We can't help you more with the info you've provided.

Comment: Usually, when working with pygame and its Sprite class, you set the `image` and `rect` attribute in the `__init__` method of your sprite subclass. You should at post the code of that class.

Comment: Fixed it, thank you